# Asprise OCR for Ipad 2

Tags: ocr

I am very new to iPAD app development. 
 I am looking to develop an iPAD 2 OCR App. Can I use Asprise OCR  to achieve this?

Regards,
Srinivas

Comment: You provide little detail about programming language and such but as Asprise comes in several 'flavours' you will most likely find a library that is suitable for your setup and needs.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract OCR is a free opensource library used by many companies, and Google supports it too.

- **https://github.com/tesseract-ocr**

It's a C/C++ library so it should be able to compile for iOs/objective-c.